# dropdown of choices works ok in browser but not open options to select in mobile devices not even in chrome device mode

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

here is my code of view and controller respectively

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem"  ng-options="option for option in typeOptions"  ng-change="changeDateRange()"  ng-init="selectedItem = typeOptions[0]"></select>

$scope.typeOptions = [
{ name: 'Feature', value: 'feature' }, 
{ name: 'Bug', value: 'bug' }, 
{ name: 'Enhancement', value: 'enhancement' }
];
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure how this worked for you in your browser but check this out. (I used Jade syntax, but you can easily adapt it to html)

```
(function(){
  'use strict'
  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('appController', ['$scope', function($scope){

      $scope.typeOptions = [
        { name: 'Feature', value: 'feature' }, 
        { name: 'Bug', value: 'bug' }, 
        { name: 'Enhancement', value: 'enhancement' }
       ];
    }])
})()


div(data-ng-app="app")
 div(ng-controller="appController")
   select.form-control(ng-model="selectedItem", ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in typeOptions track by option.value" ng-init="selectedItem=typeOptions[0]")
```

Hope this helps. Here's also the codepen link: http://codepen.io/alex06/pen/XjarJd

Comment: To clarify. This is just a solution for the code that you've posted, coming from that, it seems that it didn't work well, but try testing this on a mobile device.

Comment: thank's bro it's works i have browser issue thanks for your help

Comment: Please mark it as your solution @BilalAwan since it was downvoted, if it really helped you. :) Thank you!